# Creating newlines with cat after fixed width

Tags: r, paste, cat

I am trying to use `paste()` and `cat()` to format some text for me. I have the following variables and matrix.

```
z = 7
b = 2
dest <- 1

dummy_data <- matrix(nrow = b*dest, ncol= z)
dummy_data[is.na(dummy_data)] <- "_"
dummy_data <- paste(dummy_data,collapse=", ")
```

What I would like is to then use `cat()` on the `dummy_data` variable and have a newline break after after z elements. It seems like this should be possible using the `fill=TRUE` option but I can't figure out how. What I have is this

```
> cat(dummy_data,"\n")
_, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _, _
```

What I want is this

```
_, _, _, _, _, _, _,
_, _, _, _, _, _, _
```

How can I use `cat()` or something similar to accomplish this?

Comment: Tell us what you're actually trying to do. Are you actually trying to print out a matrix, or did you only create dummy_data matrix to illustrate what you're trying to do? Why not try the `rep()` function?

Answer (score 0):

Hi maybe there's a better way but you can do :

```
dummy_data <- matrix(nrow = b*dest, ncol= z)
dummy_data[is.na(dummy_data)] <- "_"
dummy_data <- paste(apply(dummy_data, 1, paste, collapse=", "), collapse="\n")
cat(dummy_data)

_, _, _, _, _, _, _
_, _, _, _, _, _, _
```

Comment: After adding: `dummy_data <- paste(apply(dummy_data, 1, paste, collapse=", "), collapse=",\n")`